# How to change stream<Object>'s value?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm making a chatting app.

I am using memory to implement `repository`.

In `read` method, I want to change `isReadOrNot` to `true` and return changed messages where the value `isReadOrNot` is `false` and sender and receiver are matches.

`store` is HashMap object.

```
Map<Long, Message> store = new HashMap<>();
```

I'll show you `Message` class and how I tried which have failed.

```
public class Message {
    private long index;
    private long sender_id;
    private long receiver_id;
    private Date transmitted_time;
    private Date read_time;
    private boolean readOrNot;
    private String text;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

how I tried:

```
public List<Message> read(long sender_id, long receiver_id, Date date) {
        long count = store.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(
                    message -> !message.isReadOrNot()
                            && message.getSender_id() == sender_id
                            && message.getReceiver_id() == receiver_id
                            && Long.parseLong(message.getTransmitted_time().toString()) > Long.parseLong(date.toString())
            ).count();

        return null;
    }
```

The question is how to change `receivedOrNot` value before `date` and matches with `sender_id`, `receiver_id` .

Comment: Why you are using `count` It should be `map` in your problem!

Comment: I tried to use for　sentence but failed.

Comment: *Unrelated:* What is `Date`? Certainly not a `java.util.Date`, because `date.toString()` would definitely not be something that `Long.parseLong()` could handle. If it is a `java.util.Date`, then `date.getTime()` would return the desired `long` value, though you could just use `compareTo()` like this: `message.getTransmitted_time().compareTo(date) > 0`, which is the shortest way to write it, and clearly shows the intent of the expression.

Comment: I'm using java.sql.date, not java.util.Date

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is subclass of `java.util.Date`, and `date.toString()` is still not something that Long.parseLong() could handle. My comment is equally appropriate for `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Oh. sorry. I misunderstand your first comment. I'll change that. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all the `Message` objects that pass the filter criteria should be updated with `setReadOrNot(true)`, *and* should be returned in the `List`.

If so, then you can use `peek()` and `collect(toList())`:

```java
public List<Message> read(long sender_id, long receiver_id, Date date) {
    return store.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(message -> !message.isReadOrNot()
                         && message.getSender_id() == sender_id
                         && message.getReceiver_id() == receiver_id
                         && message.getTransmitted_time().compareTo(date) > 0)
        .peek(message -> message.setReadOrNot(true))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To also set `read_time`, use a lambda expression block:

```java
        .peek(message -> {
            message.setReadOrNot(true);
            message.setRead_time(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Your understood is correct.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I want to set not only readOrNot but also read_time. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Streams is not always the best approach.  If I were doing this, I would just iterate the messages using a loop and then modify the `message` object accordingly.

```
public List<Message> read(long sender_id, long receiver_id, Date date) {
     List<Message> results = new ArrayList<>();
     for (Message message : store.values()) {
        // filter here
        if (!message.isReadOrNot()
                         && message.getSender_id() == sender_id
                         && message.getReceiver_id() == receiver_id
                         ...
                         ...
             ) {
                results.add(message);
                message.setReadOrNot(true);
                // other changes to message here
                ...
                ...
        }
     }
     return results;
}
```

Comment: What are the pros of using your answer not the previous answer?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the previous answer.  It is just a matter of personal preference.  However, the problem statement is relatively simple so no real clarification is gained by using streams.  And in this case a simple loop is more efficient (there is signficant overhead in the streams API).  But primarily for me, according to the Java API for `peek` *"This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline."* And although some ignore this advice, I tend to follow it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I'll search for more detail on what is the significant overhead. And I respect your tendency.